# Best way to encrypt data from Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to encrypt a claim through Azure AD B2C Custom Policy.

Is there a sample custom policy that provides a claim encryption transformation?

If there is no direct encryption transformation, is there any Azure REST API that can be call to encrypt a claim from the custom policy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt claims, you need to send the claim to the REST API, which can encrypt it and send it back to B2C.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there an Azure service that can be used for that  REST API call?

Comment: With in the custom policy you can integrate the REST API call. Please refer this [GitHub Sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/rest-api) which contains the custom policy and API samples.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sorry to be neat-picky, trying to understand if there is a way to leverage an existing API rather than developing another one. Basically, can AAD B2C Key Vault API be called from B2C custom policy?  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/encrypt/encrypt)